# Java scaling Image

Tags: java, android, android-layout

thanks for reading!
I have a real problem cencerning providing a image for different screen densities. The Bitmap at the top of the Screenshot is provided on a server. My App loads this PNG at startup and the PNG is loaded by

```
ImageView ivBanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_banner);
ivBanner.setImageBitmap(Statics.banner);   
ivBanner.setOnClickListener(Bannerlistener);
```

But as u can see there are some strange boarders between the image and the top/tabs.
If I put the image in the drawable folder and load it by XML as src everything is OK, scalling is right and there are no borders. But the Problem is, that I can not load it by XML!

Anybody any hints for me?
Again, thank you for reading and helping!

Greetings Andi

Screener: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/72/scaling.png/

edit:
This worked for me after trying and trying:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp" android:adjustViewBounds="true"              android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Thank you!
If you see any Problems on this code please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try to use some attributes like this :

```
ivBanner.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

else try

```
ivBanner.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
```

Comment: After trying and trying and trying, this works for me on every screen densities. Fit_XY had a Problem with the high res: